# シード値を毎回変更する方法を教えてください。

Tags: go

for文で何回か乱数を発生させ、条件を満たしていればfor文を脱出する仕組みにしたいのですが、普通に動かすと毎回同じ数値になります。そこで

```golang
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```

をfor文に入れましたが、

> .\truezundoko2.go:31(ファイル名です。): rand.Seed undefined (type [5]int has no field or method Seed)

と出ました。
以下、問題のソースコードです。

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func random(min, max int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    return rand.Intn(max - min) + min
}

func main() {
    rand := [5]int{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    i := 0
    sum := rand[4]*16+rand[3]*8+rand[2]*4+rand[1]*2+rand[0]
    kiyoshi := 0
    Rs :=  random(1,3)
    for kiyoshi < 1{
            for i = 4;i > 0; i-- {
            rand[i] = rand[i-1]}
            if  Rs == 1 {
                rand[0] = 1
                fmt.Println("Zun\n")
            }else{
                rand[0] = 0
                fmt.Println("Doko\n")
            }
        Rs =  random(1,3)
        **rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())**
        sum = rand[4]*16+rand[3]*8+rand[2]*4+rand[1]*2+rand[0]
        if(sum == 30){
                fmt.Println("Kiyoshi!!")
            kiyoshi = 1
        }
    }
}
```

わかる方、ご協力をお願いします。

Comment: 皆さんありがとうございました。おかげで問題が解決できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージのとおりです。

`main` 関数の先頭で `rand` という配列を宣言してしまっているため、パッケージ名の `rand` が上書きされてしまっています。配列を別の名前に変えれば動作します。

Answer (score 1):

random seed の設定は一度で十分なので `init()` を使う方法もあるかと思います。

# まぁ、パッケージ名と同じ名前の変数の使用は避けるべきではありますが(`math/rand` パッケージにエイリアスを付けてアクセスしても良いかも)

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math/rand"
  "time"
)

func init() {
  rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}

func random(min, max int) int {
  return rand.Intn(max-min) + min
}

func main() {
  rand := [5]int{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
  for {
    for i := 4; i > 0; i-- {
      rand[i] = rand[i-1]
    }
    if random(1, 3) == 1 {
      rand[0] = 1
      fmt.Println("Zun\n")
    } else {
      rand[0] = 0
      fmt.Println("Doko\n")
    }
    sum := rand[4]*16 + rand[3]*8 + rand[2]*4 + rand[1]*2 + rand[0]
    if sum == 30 {
      fmt.Println("Kiyoshi!!")
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 「一度で十分」というか「複数回呼び出してはいけない」です。時刻をseedにしている場合は特に。